# Android get NullPointerException for getSystemService

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to simply create an Android notification class to use it anywhere but in this code I get `NullPointerException` error for `notificationManager` variable:

```
    public class TsNotify extends Activity {
        private NotificationManager notificationManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService ( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        }

        public void notify( String title ) {
           ...
           notificationManager.notify ( NOTIFICATION_ID, notification ); 
        }
    }
```

i'm change it to this lines but this problem dont resolve:

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService ( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
```

or

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService ( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
```

`notificationManager` is NULL

Comment: Where you create your *notification* object? ( i guess it's null)

Comment: @Rami no, notificationManager is NULL

Comment: How your calling notify method ?

Comment: Use `NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);` and check

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest better approach, dont extend the activity class because you need always start that activity so your "oncreate" method gets called and notification manager gets innitialized. Have  separate Class with application context available(create on class extending application, and add it android manifest in application tag). Now in that class write overridden methods as where you want the notications like with image notication, or simple text notication, action notification.

The Null Pointer Exception is may be since your not calling start activity. And your approach is also not very clean.